# How to generate grub.conf from scratch in Fedora 14?

Tags: fedora, system-installation, grub2

[It seems that I hit following bug in Fedora 14](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=184220) - I deselected installing grub into the MBR while using the graphical installer, because I want to use an existing grub instance.

Now, I want to look up the grub.conf or menu.lst in the new installed Fedora 14 system to adjust my existing grub config - but I cannot find them anywhere.

I just information about how grub-install and gruppy are not able to create a grub.conf from scratch.

Thus my question: How to generate a grub.conf from scratch in Fedora 14, if it is missing?

**Update:** The point is to get the set of default kernel options a grub.conf includes, when created by the Fedora installer.

I have booted the fedora installation via grub and only setting the 'ro root=' options which worked.

However, it would be great if someone could post a standard generated grub stanza from his/her Fedora 14 system to see the kernel parameter differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the `grub.conf` present immediately after installation of Fedora 14 within a VirtualBox VM.  During installation I used all of the default options.

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=0
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora (2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64.img
```

Comment: thanks a lot - btw, the manpage to dracut seems to describe some Fedora specific kernel parameters that are present in that file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Fedora 14 uses the legacy version of GRUB (0.97) or the new version (1.xx); you can check by running `grub --version` on the command line. Either way the configuration file format is pretty simple; the legacy one is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/grub.html#Configuration), and the newer one [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Configuration). The newer one even comes with [`grub-mkconfig`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Invoking-grub_002dmkconfig) to generate a configuration file for you

Comment: Fedora 14 uses legacy GRUB - the syntax is not the problem: I am just worried about default kernel options that a default config file from fedora might include, but I don't know anything about ...